# Trouble deleting iptables rules

Tags: iptables

I previously added the following rules:

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp — dport 80 -j REDIRECT — to-port 3000
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp — dport 443 -j REDIRECT — to-port 8000
```

Now I need to remove them. I tried first listing them with `sudo iptables -L INPUT --line-numbers` but they didn't appear there. How do I remove them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding rules to the PREROUTING chain of the NAT table, but you try listing them from the INPUT chain of the default (filter) table.

That will not show the rules you've added.

You should specify the NAT table (`-t nat`) and the PREROUTING chain (`-L PREROUTING`) in your list command. So, the correct command is:

`sudo iptables -t nat -L PREROUTING --line-numbers`

You can remove the rules simply by changing the `-A` (add) of the command that created them into a `-D` (delete). So the commands you can use to remove the rules become:

```
sudo iptables -D PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp — dport 80 -j REDIRECT — to-port 3000
sudo iptables -D PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp — dport 443 -j REDIRECT — to-port 8000
```